# How can I get the value of multiple keys if I find it in a loop?

Tags: javascript

```
var charCodes = {
    "a": ". _",
        "b": "_ . . .",
        "c": "_ . _ .",
        "d": "_ . .",
        "e": ".",
        "f": ". . _ .",
        "g": "_ _ .",
        "h": ". . . .",
        "i": ". .",
        "j": ". _ _ _",
        "k": "_ . _",
        "l": ". _ . .",
        "m": "_ _",
        "n": "_ .",
        "o": "_ _ _",
        "p": ". _ _ .",
        "q": "_ _ . _",
        "r": ". _ .",
        "s": ". . .",
        "t": "_",
        "u": ". . _",
        "v": ". . . _",
        "w": ". _ _",
        "x": "_ . . _",
        "y": "_ _ . .",
        "z": ". _ _ _ _"
};

var temp;
var abc = "abcdefghi";
for(i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    var temp = abc[i].split(".");
    for(x = 0; x < charCodes.length; i++) {
        temp = charCodes[x];
    }
} 

console.log(temp);
```

I want to convert the string abc to morse code.
And it's still not working for me.
I've split the string and now trying to match it to charCodes array so i can get the string value to temp in morse code.

Comment: Don't use HTML comments in JS code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain exactly what happens when you run this program and why that's not suitable for your needs. Your code doesn't make sense to me, as it looks like you're just looping over the dictionary itself and only logging the value for the 'a' key.

Comment: In your code comment you say you want to loop through your array and in the explanation you say, you want to transform a string to a morse code. And in the subject you want to get the value of multiple keys (if found). So what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't loop through the `charCodes` dictionary at all to convert a string to morse code. The point of the dictionary format is to be able to reference a value by its key. That's what the `abc[character]` syntax is for.

What you need to do is loop over the string to be decoded, `abc` in this case, and then get the morse code value of each character you find. You don't need to split the string, because a string can already be referenced by index like an array.

As you loop through you can add the values you get from the `charCodes` to your result variable with string concatenation. And when the loop is done you'll have a long string containing the morse code.

```
var abc = "abcde fghi";
var result = "";
for(i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    if (abc[i] in charCodes){
        result += charCodes[abc[i]];
    } else {
        //Handle non letter results here
    }
}
```

You can use `if (abc[i] in charCodes)` to make sure you only try to convert existing keys (eg. you don't have a space defined in your `charCodes`). Then decide how you want to handle that, whether it's throwing an error or adding a new line (`result += '\n'`).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping, you can use [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to use [Array instance methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods) on the string. E.g.

```
Array.prototype.map.call('sos', function(c){ return charCodes[c]; }).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another loop to iterate through the text you're trying to convert.

```
var s = 'text to encode'
for (var x = 0; x < s.length(); x++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < charCodes.length; i++) {
      if (charCodes[i].indexOf(s[x]) != -1) {
          temp = charCodes[i];
          console.log(temp);
      }
  }
}
```